# form submit using jquery ajax with button type not submit type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to submit a form using FormData() but in the form i use a button with `type="button"` instead of type="submit" which will refresh the page. I tried to search on google for solution but so far couldn't find the right answer or a clear answer. I will be posting a simple form with 3 inputs and start from here if i want to go bigger. When i `var_dump[$_POST]` i get empty `array[0]{}`
please help.

```js
$("#discussion_submit_button").on("click", function(e){
//$("#discussion_form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = $("#discussion_title").val();
    var discussion = $("#discussion_input_textarea").val();

    if (title == '' || discussion == '') { 
        $(".discussion_label_arrow, .discussion_required_fields").fadeIn("Slow");
        // error message, we select span tag with ID error_message and we change its content to this text
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.discussion_label_arrow, .discussion_required_fields').fadeOut("Slow");
        }, 2000); 
    } else {
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        alert(formData);
        $.ajax({
            url: "widgets/discussion_board_submit.php",
            method: "POST",
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData,
            success:function(data){
                //alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="" class="discussion_form" id="discussion_form">
        <div class="discussion_label_div"><span class="discussion_label_span">Title</span><span class="discussion_label_arrow"><span></div>
        <div class="discussion_input_div"><input type="text" name="discussion_title" class="discussion_input" size="50" id="discussion_title"/></div>

        <div class="discussion_label_div"><span class="discussion_label_span">Subject</span><span class="discussion_label_arrow"><span></div>

        <div class="discussion_label_div"><span class="discussion_label_span">Discussion</span><span class="discussion_label_arrow"><span></div>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="discussion_textarea" class="discussion_input_textarea" placeholder="Open your discussion..." id="discussion_input_textarea"></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="discussion_submit_button" value="Assert" class="share_button" id="discussion_submit_button"/>
    </form>
```

and this is my php :

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: Use `.on('submit')` on the form, not `.on('click')` on the button. Then you can cancel the submit default event (i.e. to load page).

Comment: so by using .preventDefault(); i cancel the page reload ? but what wouldnt a normal button type not work ?

Comment: Because the page reload is an action of the `submit` event, NOT the `click` event. You're canceling the default action of the `click` event, which is effectively nothing in this case.

Comment: ok this i am getting data now array(4) {
  ["discussion_title"]=>
  string(5) "title"
  ["discussion_link"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["discussions_subjects"]=>
  string(8) "Outdoors"
  ["discussion_textarea"]=>
  string(5) "hello"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you pass *this* to *FormData* constructor, but it requires form element to initialize object.

You can do this:

```
var formData = new FormData(this.form);
```

or just pick form from DOM:

```
var formData = new FormData($("#discussion_form")[0]);
```

---

Just remember you have to pass *HTMLFormElement* to *FormData*, so you can't use jQuery object. That is why I pick first element from the jQuery array.

Comment: ok so i must enter the form because i saw on some places that it is empty, but what does it mean ($("#discussion_form")[0]) ? i mean the [0] what does it mean what array is this ?

Comment: [0] is required to pick HTMLElement, because we can't pass jQuery object to FormData

Comment: and when do i use [1] for example in which case ?

Comment: You can use [1], [2], etc. to pick different elements that meet your selector condition. Eg. you do $("form"), so jQuery will return object with every form found on your page. That's why you have to pick one element from jQuery object. In your case you pick specific form with specific Id, so there should be only one element in array. That is why I wrote [0] :D

Comment: ah ok i see so if i have many form on the page i then have to pick them but here i am using an id so wouldn't that be enough to pick the needed form ?

Comment: It is enough. Problem is that by using $(smth) you will get jQuery object, but you need form itself, so you have to pick it from inside of that jQuery data. 

It's all about types :)

Comment: well i tested with only the ID but it did not work i have to add [0] for it to work :/

Comment: Yes, because as I explained you need to get Html element from what jQuery returned you (if you use ID there should be only one item in jQuery array). Please just remember that using this.form will be best option in most cases (because JS automatically set this field to form in which button, input or other controls are).

Comment: ok thanks a lot man things worked out, and i added an upload image option in the same form, i managed to update the table with the image path but still having a problem uploading the file itself

Comment: Glad I was able to help you. Please remember that uploaded files are in $_FILES variable in PHP. It would be nice, if you will consider marking my answer as solution (or at least upvote) :P

Comment: thanks a lot Shorek appreciate it :) well how to consider your answer as a solution ? i will upvote of course

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171455/discussion-between-skorek-and-firashelou).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of validating the form with javascript add a `required` attribute to the fields that can't be empty.

If you like You can use css styling such as `:invalid` to style them
user will get focus on the first element that is wrong and will be able to correct it when they try to submit it.
but that can't happen unless the submit event is triggered which won't happen if you use a `button.onclick` or a `type="button"` and prevent the flow. And that is your mistake.

when you construct your formdata the argument becomes a button element and not a form which the FormData requires

```
new FormData(this); // <-- `this` is a button elm in your case
```

---

So when you use [constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation), then submit event will only get trigger if all fields are valid. So you will always have a valid form on the submit event and `this` will be referred to the form element which you need for the FormData

So here is what i should have done:

```js
function form2ajax(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  var formData = new FormData(this);
  
  // Having html define the markup
  // makes you able to reuse this function
  // for other forms
  $.ajax({
    url: this.action,
    method: this.method,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
      //alert(data);
    }
  });
  
  // Just Another solution to submit the form...
  // fetch(this.action, {method: this.method, body: formData})
  //   .then(res => res.text())
  //   .then(console.log)
}

$("#discussion_form").submit(form2ajax)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="widgets/discussion_board_submit.php" class="discussion_form" id="discussion_form">
  <div class="discussion_label_div">
    <span class="discussion_label_span">Title</span>
    <span class="discussion_label_arrow"><span> <!-- note missing / in span -->
  </div>
  <div class="discussion_input_div">
    <!-- note required attribute -->
    <input type="text" required name="discussion_title" class="discussion_input" size="50" id="discussion_title"/>
  </div>
    
  <div class="discussion_label_div">
    <span class="discussion_label_span">Subject</span>
    <span class="discussion_label_arrow"><span> <!-- note missing / in span -->
  </div>
      
  <div class="discussion_label_div">
    <span class="discussion_label_span">Discussion</span>
    <span class="discussion_label_arrow"><span> <!-- note missing / in span -->
  </div>
  
  <!-- note required attribute -->
  <textarea required rows="5" cols="50" name="discussion_textarea" class="discussion_input_textarea" placeholder="Open your discussion..." id="discussion_input_textarea"></textarea>
  
  <!-- note using type=submit instead of type=button -->
  <!-- type=button don't trigger a submit -->
  <input type="submit" name="discussion_submit_button" value="Assert" class="share_button" id="discussion_submit_button"/>
</form>
```

Comment: ok will do that but i have a question i read somewhere that required attribute is not valid on all browser so wouldn't that be a problem ?

Comment: Nope. When browser doesn't support something it will just skip it.